# Make the exe run on lower version of framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

I am creating an exe from my C# application and adding some `dlls` like

```
SFXmaker.cp = new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters();
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
```

The problem is that I'm using .NET Framework 4.0 and when I run the extractor on .NET 2.0 it crashes. Can anybody tell me how to make the `exe` run on .NET 2.0 created from .NET 4 application?

[Example I am referencing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339768/Flexible-Self-Extracting-Application-in-Csharp-Pro)

Comment: Did you try targeting the 2.0 framework when you built the project?

Comment: im creating a archive of files from a c# application that is build targeting the .net 4 framework and from that application i want to create an archive that could run on .net2 framework

Comment: I don't think you can do that.  You'd have to build a separate archive that targets .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compile the project with .net 2.0 when you build it.

If you are using a IDE like Visual studio, just right click on the project and select "properties" there you will see the target framework.

Answer (score 1):

A .NET assembly compiled for .NET 4.0 will **never** run in the .NET 2.0 CLR. You *must* recompile it for .NET 2.0.

Comment: i dont want to run the `.net4` compiled assembly on `.net2` i want to run the exe generated by it on .net2, the `dlls` im adding by `cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");` command are version 4 can i add version 2 dlls? is there a compiler option that i can set? or i have to manually provide the path to version 2 dlls?

Comment: I am not sure if you understand that an `exe` is an *assembly*. You cannot run a `dll` or `exe` targeting .NET 4.0 with the .NET 2.0 CLR.